# Problem on Malus law? Doesn't work on certain angles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, polarization

> If unpolarized light falls on two polarizing sheets placed one on top of other, what must be the angle between the characteristics directions of the sheet
>
> a) if the intensity of the transmitted light is 1/3 of the maximum intensity of the incident beam,
>
> b) if the intensity is 1/3 of the incident light problem arises in understanding 1/3 of the max intensity and 1/3 of incident light?

I obtained this solution for the (a) part.
(A) Let max intensity that passes the sheets at 0$^{\circ}$ be $ I_m $
and incident intensity be $I_1$, I

therefore, $I_1$ = $I_m$ cos$^2$ x , at 0$^{\circ}$
$I_1$ = $I_m$.

as given, $I_2$ = $1\over 3$ $I_m$ ... (1)

by malus law, $I_2$ = $I_m\cdot \cos^2 x$

substituting from (1) we get

$\cos^2 x = {1\over3}$ or $x = + \text{ or} - (54.73) \approx + \text{ or} - (55^{\circ}$)

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: I am not asking anybody to solve the problem for me, half of the problem is solved and mentioned in the post, asking for hints to proceed further. I dont think that is against the stack exchange policy otherwise not stated.

Comment: *I dont think that is against the stack exchange policy* Yes it is, as stated in the two links I provided. We're not a homework help site, we're a Q&A site for physics concepts. You could make the post on-topic if you asked about the specific concept that is preventing you from solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what is being asked for part (b), but I will just explain a little about Malus's law.

Polarizing filters block all light except that which travels in a single direction, vertical or horizontal [see note below]. Unpolarized light contains both horizontal and vertical components, so the first polarizer blocks either all the horizontal light, or all the vertical light. So, *unpolarized light which passes through a single polarizer is decreased by a factor of 1/2*, or

$$I_1=\frac{1}{2}I_0$$

Now, Malus's law tells us that light passing through a polarizer decreases by a factor of $\cos^2\theta$, but that's only for *light which has already been polarized*. So each of your polarizers decreases the intensity of the incoming light - the first one by $1/2$, the second by $\cos^2\theta$.

NOTE: Polarization direction. When I say "vertical and horizontal", I am referring to the direction of the electric and magnetic fields in an electromagnetic wave. If an electromagnetic wave is moving towards you, the electric field points one direction (say vertically) and the magnetic field points the other (say horizontally).